# is it possible to set a parameter for selecting a table?

Tags: sql, vb.net

sorry for the noob question..but here's what i did

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Declare @mychar varchar(60) " & _
                              "Set @mychar = '" & TextBox2.Text & "'" & _
                              "Select * from @mychar", conn)
    Dim rdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
    While rdr.Read()
        ListView2.Items.Add(rdr("Account"))
    End While
    rdr.Close()
```

but i get an error saying "Must declare the table variable "@mychar"." what's wrong ? or is this not just possible ? thanks in advance..

Comment: you can add the param by 'cmd.Parameter.AddWithValue("@mychar",variable)'

Comment: By looking at your code, it looks like you want to construct dynamic query where table name is coming from TextBox2.Text. You dont need parameter for that. Just concatenate the TextBox2.Text to the select query. "Select * from " & TextBox2.Text

Comment: yeah..i just did that and it's awesome ! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(" Select * from " & TextBox2.Text & " ", conn)
    Dim rdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
    While rdr.Read()
        ListView2.Items.Add(rdr("Account"))
    End While
    rdr.Close()
```